# How to read log file from s3 (cloudtrail) in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail

I have just started using aws and have no idea on how to read log files in lambda from s3 that have been created by CloudTrail (using python-boto3)

Comment: This might assist you: [Tutorial: Triggering a Lambda function with AWS CloudTrail events - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign a role to the lambda function that has IAM permissions to read the object in S3.  A detailed walkthrough can be found from [AWS here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign proper permissions to your IAM role.
For code - Use boto3 library (AWS - SDK) to write lambda function.

Code for lambda handler:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Goal 1: Read file from csv
    object_key = "event_history_j.json"  # Name of file
    bucket = "demo-cloudtrail-logs-ec2"  # Name of bucket
    client = boto3.client("s3")
    data = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=object_key)["Body"].read()
    return data
```